# Query to pull with timestamps that were updated more than 30m ago not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have racked my brain trying to solve this.  Everything seems to check out, but its not working how I'd expect :(

I have an index `test-index` with the following documents:

```
{
        "_index": "test-index",
        "_type": "testType",
        "_id": "AV33b_VYUyX1XZAq7NTI",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "timestamp": "2017-08-17T17:56:55"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test-index",
        "_type": "testType",
        "_id": "AV33cBN4UyX1XZAq7NTJ",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "timestamp": "2017-08-18T17:11:12"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test-index",
        "_type": "testType",
        "_id": "AV33cetJUyX1XZAq7NTK",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "timestamp": "2017-08-19T17:11:12"
        }
      }
```

It can be seen here that I have

1. A document that was, theoretically, last updated yesterday.
2. A document that was last updated today (08/18) 20 minutes ago (now = 17:30 at time of writing this post)
3. A document that was "last updated" tomorrow, just to show why I am confused why this isn't working.

I have the following query:

```
GET test-index/testType/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "lte": "now-30m"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It pulls the record updated today (20 minutes ago), and the one updated yesterday.  I would have expected it to only pull the record yesterday.

```
"hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test-index",
        "_type": "testType",
        "_id": "AV33b_VYUyX1XZAq7NTI",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "timestamp": "2017-08-17T17:56:55"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test-index",
        "_type": "testType",
        "_id": "AV33cBN4UyX1XZAq7NTJ",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "timestamp": "2017-08-18T17:11:12"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Changing the query to `gte now-30m`, it works as expected and pulls the record with the timestamp of tomorrow.  The range query works properly if I change it to `lte now-1d` as well, showing only the 08/17 record as expected, but I'd like use a minute cutoff.  The same misbahavior can also be observed when I try to do hours as well.

I have tried setting my format to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and accepting ES's default mapping for date as well, with no luck.

Anyone know what might be wrong here?

EDIT: It also seems to pull records for "today", but a time in the future as well, such as:

```
 {
        "_index": "test-index",
        "_type": "testType",
        "_id": "AV33gSs6UyX1XZAq7NTS",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "timestamp": "2017-08-18 19:11:12"
        }
      }
```

It would seem its a precision issue, I just don't know what the issue is, since everything seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I ended up finding out what the root cause of this is.  When indexing documents, ES is treating the supplied values as UTC date/times.  When querying, ES uses the UTC date/time for `now` to compare to timestamps that are indexed.

Given that I am 5 hours behind UTC and I was indexing documents using my local date/timezone, my query was essentially saying "give me dates that are less than 5 hours - 30 minutes from now.

This is the query I ended up writing to see what values it was literally comparing, with what I had to do to bring about the "expected" result inside the bool query:

```
GET test-index/testType/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "script" : {
          "script" : {
            "inline": "doc['timestamp'].value < new Date().getTime() - (5 * 60 * 60 * 1000) - (120 * 60 * 1000)",
            "lang": "painless"
           }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "timestampValue" : {
      "script" : "doc['timestamp'].value"
    },
    "valueTimestampMustBeLessThan" : {
      "script" : "new Date().getTime() - (120 * 60 * 1000)"
    },
    "now" : {
      "script" : "new Date().getTime()"
    },
    "subtract": {
      "script": "(120 * 60 * 1000)"
    },
    "timestamp" : {
      "script" : "doc['timestamp']"
    },
    "lt?" : {
      "script" : "doc['timestamp'].value < new Date().getTime() - (120 * 60 * 1000)"
    },
    "gt?" : {
      "script" : "doc['timestamp'].value > new Date().getTime() - (120 * 60 * 1000)"
    }
  }
}
```

An example:

- A document that I inserted at 08/18/2017 at around 6:40pm reads its UTC time as that and its "local" time as 1:40pm.
- A query that I run at 08/18/2017 at around 6:41pm reads `now`'s UTC time as 11:41pm, and its "local" time as 6:41pm.

There are numerous spots in ES documentation that mention that it uses dates in UTC, such as:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#CO160-2

But I fully never understood the implications until now.

In what I am doing, I just need to ensure that my app is inserting UTC times, especially given varying timezones.